# Android notification image size

Tags: android, android-notifications

what is the magic with the notification image?

[image: my notification]

You can see that the image is not as big as possible, it has a border.

[image: google notification]

But the examples from Google doesn't have this border.

What I have to do to get my image without this border? I use the "Normal view" notification and call setLargeIcon(). The image is 250dp x 250dp.

Comment: Are you using match_parent for the height and width properties of the image view? Also, what is the ImageView a child to in terms of layout?

Comment: How exactly is your image 250x250 DP? images can only be in pixels.

Comment: Are you sure your image doesn't have an opaque white background?